# Problem installing ShellEd plugin in Eclipse neon cdt

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I installed ShellEd plugin for my eclipse(neon) cdt .

But the syntax highlight do not work with bash file, and i found

> window > Preferences > Shell Script > Editor > Folding > Syntax
>   coloring

the Element CheckBox "Enable" is gray , can not be checked .

do you know how to fix this problem ?

Comment: i use eclipse in windows

Comment: Could you provide a link to the plugin in question? Have you tried reaching out to the plugin's developers / support?